# posting to an existing object through postman

Tags: java, postman

[pic related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLCY4.png)

So as the picture shows, I want to add the new todos through a manual POST on postman. It should post it to user_id: 2 and the todo should appear under user_id when a get is done.

Below is the mapping code that calls the method to add the todo through a post request

````
    public Todo plusTodo(@PathVariable("id") User user) {
        //List<Todo> userTodos = userService.plusTodo(user);
        return userService.plusTodo(user);
    }```
````

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i post a nested json object? I want to post what is in the body into user_id. The picture has an object that I am trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create REST controller with

```
@RestController 
@PostMapping(value = "/users/{id}")
```

annotations. And add to your `pom.xml` dependency allowing to return JSON as result

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you share the complete payload and also the corresponding DTO (java class mapped to the payload).
I assuming that you're asking that how can you post an array of JSON payload through a POST call. First of all you should have POJO say 'User' corresponding the JSON schema. Now create another POJO class say 'Users' that will hold a list of User.

```
 @PostMapping...
 public Todo plusTodo(@RequestBody Users users) {
    ....
  }
```

Now you may pass an array of user json in the pay load and try.

If you dont want to create another POJO, you may try this as well.

```
public Todo plusTodo(@RequestBody List<User> users){
   ....
}
```